# Net Remoting: Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой: есть небольшое приложение использующее технологию Net Remoting. Так же есть 3 машины, на одной выполняется серверная часть приложения, на двух других клиентские. Клиентские части отправляют на сервер множество параллельных запросов, симулируя работу двухсот пользователей. Если запускать только одного клиента, все запросы проходят успешно. Но если запустить двух клиентов одновременно, то возникнет ошибка

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета (протокол/сетевой адрес/порт)
   в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   в System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ExclusiveTcpListener.Start(Boolean exclusiveAddressUse)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.StartListening(Object data)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupChannel()
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(Int32 port)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(Int32 port)
   в NetRemotingClient.Client.ServerClass.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\vgeorg\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\NetRemotingClient\Program.cs:строка 27
```

Код сервера:

```
   Console.WriteLine("ServerSide....");
   var serverChannel = new TcpChannel(2222);
   ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(serverChannel, false);

 RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType
         (typeof(Greatings), "Greatings",   WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the server....");
```

Код клиента:

```
 Greatings grt = (Greatings) Activator.GetObject(typeof(Greatings), "tcp://192.168.13.121:2222/Greatings");
 grt.PrintText(Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).HostName + " Time: " + DateTime.Now);
```

Передаваемый объект:

```
   public class Greatings : MarshalByRefObject
   {
      public Greatings()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Constructor called");

      }
      ~Greatings()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Deconstructir called");
      }

      public void PrintText(string txt)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Hey you need to print : {0}", txt);
      }
   }
```

Netstat для одного из клиентов (192.168.13.111) говорит, что на клиенте используются разные порты:

```
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58007   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58008   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58020   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58021   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58035   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58036   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58037   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58039   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58041   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.13.121:2222    192.168.13.111:58044   ESTABLISHED
```

Следовательно вопросы:

1. почему так происходит?
2. как избавиться от ошибки?

UPD:

```
{"Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 192.168.13.121:2222"}


Server stack trace: 
   в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(EndPoint ipEndPoint)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket()
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.GetSocket()
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   в System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   в Common.Greatings.PrintText(String txt)
   в NetRemotingClient.Client.ServerClass.RunClient() в C:\Users\vgeorg\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\NetRemotingClient\Program.cs:строка 19
   в NetRemotingClient.Client.ServerClass.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\vgeorg\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\NetRemotingClient\Program.cs:строка 13
```

Что интересно в логах сервера вызвался деструктор и запросы продолжили вызываться дальше:

```
Hey you need to print : PC-08.akforta.local Time: 25.12.2017 9:48:39
Deconstructir called
Hey you need to print : PC-21.akforta.local Time: 25.12.2017 9:48:39
Hey you need to print : PC-08.akforta.local Time: 25.12.2017 9:48:39
Hey you need to print : PC-08.akforta.local Time: 25.12.2017 9:48:38
Hey you need to print : PC-21.akforta.local Time: 25.12.2017 9:48:39
```

Comment: так же возникает следующая ошибка "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение", но думаю, она появляется как следствие первой

Comment: Судя по трассировке стека, вы на клиенте вызываете конструктор TcpChannel передавая ему порт - но в вопросе я этого кода не вижу.

Comment: вот полный код клиента https://pastebin.com/nT4qsCW5

Comment: К прочтению: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178779)

Comment: Похоже, что у вас падает обработчик исключений. То есть настоящая ошибка - другая. Кстати, зачем вам такой обработчик исключений?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov добавил ошибку, которая падает без обработчика исключений